# React.js Have to press button twice for register

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, use-ref

I have this website where Ive build an login system.

**Register.jsx**

```
export default function Register() {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
    const history = useHistory();

    const emailRef = useRef();
    const passwordRef = useRef();
    const usernameRef = useRef();

    const handleStart = () => {
        setEmail(emailRef.current.value);
    };
    const handleFinish = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setUsername(usernameRef.current.value);
        setPassword(passwordRef.current.value);
        try {
            await axios.post("auth/register", {username, email, password });
            history.push("/login");
        } catch (err) {}
    };
    return (
        .......
                {!email ? (
                    <div className="input">
                        <input type="email" placeholder="email address" ref={emailRef} />
                        <button className="registerButton" onClick={handleStart}>
                            Get Started
                        </button>
                    </div>
                ) : (
                    <form className="input">
                        <input type="username" placeholder="username" ref={usernameRef} />
                        <input type="password" placeholder="password" ref={passwordRef} />
                        <button className="registerButton" onClick={handleFinish}>
                            Start
                        </button>
                    </form>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**my auth route**

```
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
    const newUser = new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
            req.body.password,
            process.env.SECRET_KEY
        ).toString(),
    });
    try {
        const user = await newUser.save();
        res.status(201).json(user);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }
});
```

When I click the button the first time the payload in the console looks like this :

```
email: "test9@gmail.com"
password: ""
username: ""
```

and it fails. But when I press a second time:

```
email: "test9@gmail.com"
password: "123456"
username: "test9"
```

it works and everything is in my database. What can be the issue here? Ive pretty much tried everything.

Comment: Any reason you are using useRef to track input values

Answer (score 2):

You are using state values directly after updating them. They won't reflect the updated values until next render cylce.

That is exactly why the value of email is correct. And the rest are blank. Email was **set** in the previous cycle with

```
 setEmail(emailRef.current.value);
```

Update your code with this. It should work :

```
        setUsername(usernameRef.current.value);
        setPassword(passwordRef.current.value);
        try {
            await axios.post("auth/register", {usernameRef.current.value, email, passwordRef.current.value });
            history.push("/login");
        } catch (err) {}
```

Comment: Two recommendations: 1) Use [controlled inputs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) rather than trying to access DOM values via `useRef` as @tushar recommended; 2) Set those values (e.g. `usernameRef.current.value) into variables so you Don't Repeat Yourself.

Comment: I have asked exactly that in the comments. @lorijames95