# Array state not pushing elements correctly from input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to collect elements from an input field in React. I have a state with an empty array, but when I try to push an element into it, the resulting array is always one element late.
What I mean is that if I enter a number into the array and I console.log it nothing happens, but if I insert another, then I'm able to see the previous one.
This is what I tried, the submitWeight function is triggered by a submit button.

Code:

```
const [inputWeight, setInputWeight] = useState("");
const [weight, setWeight] = useState([]);

const submitWeight = () => {
    setWeight([...weight, inputWeight]);
  };
```

And here's the JSX portion:

```
<div className="input-container">
          <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setInputWeight(e.target.value)} />
          <button onClick={submitWeight}>SUBMIT</button>
        </div>
```

Full component:

```
const MainContainer = () => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [recipeOfTheDay, setRecipeOfTheDay] = useState("");
  const [recipeImg, setRecipeImg] = useState("");
  const [quoteOfTheDay, setQuoteOfTheDay] = useState("");
  const [modalClass, setModalClass] = useState("closed");
  const [inputWeight, setInputWeight] = useState("");
  const [weight, setWeight] = useState([]);

  //FUNZIONI
  const openClass = () => {
    setModalClass("open");
  };

  const closedClass = () => {
    setModalClass("closed");
  };

  const submitWeight = () => {
    setWeight([...weight, inputWeight]);
    console.log(weight);
  };

  //API
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://zenquotes.io/api/random/9b5ee37d2eebfa303c900da058c17eaa914c5709"
      )
      .then((res) => setQuoteOfTheDay(res.data[0].q))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    axios
      .get(
        "https://api.edamam.com/api/recipes/v2?type=public&q=beef&app_id=68835608&app_key=%20a13f4a407eb56c9970ab3732c77bc8cb%09&diet=high-protein&random=true"
      )
      .then((res) => setRecipeOfTheDay(res.data.hits[0].recipe.label))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));

    axios
      .get(
        "https://api.edamam.com/api/recipes/v2?type=public&q=beef&app_id=68835608&app_key=%20a13f4a407eb56c9970ab3732c77bc8cb%09&diet=high-protein&random=true"
      )
      .then((res) => setRecipeImg(res.data.hits[0].recipe.image))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="main-container">
      <div className="div-1">
        <img src={logo} alt="logo" className="logo" />
      </div>
      <div className="div-2">
        <h1>
          {date.getDate()} {date.getMonth()} {date.getFullYear()}
        </h1>
      </div>
      <div className="div-3">
        <h1>Add Weight</h1>
        <img
          src={plussign}
          alt="plus sign"
          className="plus-sign"
          onClick={openClass}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="div-4">
        <h1>ok</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="div-5">
        <div className="quote-container">
          <div className="quote-subcontainer">
            <h1>Quote Of The Day:</h1>
            <p>{quoteOfTheDay}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          className="recipe-container"
          style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${recipeImg})` }}
        >
          <div className="recipe-subcontainer">
            <h1>Recipe Of The Day:</h1>
            <p>{recipeOfTheDay}</p>
            <img src={showmore} alt="show more" className="show-more" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="div-6">
        <div className="weight-history-container">
          <p>Enter your weight to start tracking.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className={`page-mask ${modalClass}`}></div>
      <div className={`modal-add-weight ${modalClass}`}>
        <p>What's your weight today?</p>
        <div className="input-container">
          <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setInputWeight(e.target.value)} />
          <h1> kg</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="modal-button-container">
          <button onClick={submitWeight}>SUBMIT</button>
          <button onClick={closedClass}>CLOSE</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you include the code that logs `weight`? Including the full component source would probably be helpful too.

Comment: React does not update state immediately. Check in useEffect : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70422709/react-js-have-to-press-button-twice-for-register/70422782#70422782

Answer (score 2):

The `setState` or in your case `setWeight` function is async. So, when you call `console.log` directly under the `setWeight`, the function didn't execute yet, thus showing you the old value.

If you want to `console.log` the new one, or do something once the state changes, you can use the `useEffect` hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(weight)
}, [weight])
```

If you want to read more about why setting state is async, you can find it in the docs here: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: Works beautifully! Thank you!